# Cygwin: How to switch sshd service to a different domain user

Tags: ssh, cygwin

As have many, apparently, I struggle to find a forum to ask Cygwin questions.  (Cygwin.com has a mailing list.  How quaint.)

We have a number of Windows servers running cygwin sshd for administrative purposes.  They all run as a domain account, let's call it my_domain\cyg_server.

Recently upper management required that we break out the account for development and production.  So on the development machines, I have to change an existing sshd service from running as my_domain\cyg_server to my_domain\cyg_dev.

So, I've verified that my_domain\cyg_dev exists and belongs to the same A/D groups as cyg_server, and that I can log into the server as either cyg_server or cyg_dev.

I've added cyg_dev to the local administrator group.

I've changed the existing CYGWIN sshd service to run as cyg_dev.

With the service down, I've re-run ssh-host-config from a cygwin shell that was started with "Run as administrator".  I answered "yes" to all questions.

I note that /etc/ssh* are now all owned by cyg_dev, as I would expect.

I started the service, and it started correctly, and runs as cyg_dev.

When I attempt to log into localhost as myself, I get:

/bin/bash: Operation not permitted

I *can* log in as my_domain\cyg_dev.

This is usually an indication that the account that sshd runs as, does not have admin privileges.  But I confirm that my_domain\cyg_dev is in the administrators group.

I tried updating /etc/passwd with all domain accounts, and that didn't affect the problem.

I'm not sure what to try at this point.  I've considered deleting /etc/ssh_host* and then running ssh-host-config again and hope the files are recreated.  Is this worth trying, or will it make things worse?

Comment: Ask the mailing list. I see no reason and utility for the change from `cyg_server` to `cyg_dev` .  It an auxiliary user to separate the sshd service from the system one; no one is supposed to log in a shell from it.

Comment: I see no utility in making the change either, but nevertheless we are required to do so.  We have spent a lot of time and effort arguing that position to no avail.

Comment: cyg_server is just a default name. You can config sshd and when the configure script suggests to use cyg_server just change to cyg_dev.